# xml parsing returns html, how to get the text of it python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am parsing an xbrl file using minidom. I find the following using getElementsByTagName

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-left: 0px; width: 650px; border-bottom: 0px; border-collapse: collapse"  width="100%"><tr><td colspan="1">Independent auditor's report on the financial statements</td></tr></table><br><table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-left: 0px; width: 650px; border-bottom: 0px; border-collapse: collapse"  width="100%"><tr><td colspan="1">We have audited the financial statements of KPMG Statsautoriseret Revisionspartnerselskab for the financial year 11 December 2013 – 31 December 2014. The financial statements comprise income statement, balance sheet, statement of changes in equity, cash flow statement accounting policies and notes. The financial statements are prepared in accordance with the Danish Financial Statements Act.</td></tr></table>
```

Now I want to get only the text out of that, how should I proceed? Should I maybe go with beautifulsoup from now on?

The entire file can be found at [here](http://regnskaber.virk.dk/89187552/ZG9rdW1lbnRsYWdlcjovLzAzLzM2L2UzL2ViL2Y4LzM5YzItNGU2ZC05OTY2LWQxOGUyOTQzNjIzYw.xml) and the field that I am looking at is `<arr:AuditorsReportOnFinancialStatements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(auditorsReportOnAuditedFS[0].firstChild.data)
    items = soup.find_all('td')
    listForString = []
    for item in items:
        listForString.append(item.text.encode('utf-8').strip())
    result.append(' : '.join(['AuditorsReportOnFinancialStatements', ' - '.join(listForString)]))
```

This works